# How to calculate time complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I get a series of roots from 0 to (n-1), but how to count it, I do not understand. Am I thinking in the wrong direction?

```
for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    int j = 0;
    while (j * j < i) {
        ++j;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "series of roots"? `j * j` will always be zero on the first iteration, and will quickly become `>= i` causing the inner loop not to run very much. Are you sure you translated this correctly?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Inner loop complexity is O(sqrt(i)).

Comment: @OneCricketeer So they mean √0 + √1 + √2 + ... + √(n-1) and want to know O(n√n).

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I understand that inner loop complexity is O (sqrt (i)). This is how I came to √0 + √1 + √2 + ... + √ (n-1). But I can't figure out how O (n√n) follows from it. Is it O(i*√n) = O(n√n)?

Comment: @Sergey You can see it being sqrt, because it will only do sqrt iterations. The inverse of j^2 is a sqrt and j^2 grows faster than O(n).

Comment: And one of the hardest things to comprehend about complexity is what you are actually measuring. Are you measuring how many times j is incremented or how many comparisons are happening. You have to be very clear about what exactly you are measuring. This is something that many professionals actually struggle with.

Comment: Big O notation is worst case scenario. In the worst case, N is the largest number (most inner loop iterations), or `while (j * j < n-1)`. Rather than n√n, could write O(n^(3/2))

Comment: @HSchmale I guess it's even harder to comprehend that the j-increments and the comparisons lead to the same complexity class so that it doesn't matter and they don't need to be any clearer about that :-)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Sum of sqrt(1) + ... + sqrt(n) can be viewed as the [generalized harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalizations) of order -1/2 of n.

The [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) gives the sum to be:

[image: sum of generalized harmonic number]

Easy to see that the number is bounded by O(psqrt(p))

You can learn more about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241864/sum-of-square-roots-formula).